# como usar el SwitchPreference con sharedpreferences

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, sharedpreferences, huawei-mobile-services, hms-core

Buenas noches estoy implementando un mapa con preferencias, que obtiene el valor de mi configuracion pero no habilita el trafico

```
boolean trafico;

trafico=PreferenciasAjustes.modoTrafico;

hMap.setTrafficEnabled(trafico);
```

no habilita el trafico pero si  pongo

`hMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);`

si se habilita,lei los valores de trafico y si se obtiene true y false.

```
<SwitchPreferenceCompat app:key="modoTrafico" app:title="Habilitar tráfico" app:summary="Habilitado solo en modo Normal" android:defaultValue="false" app:icon="@drawable/ic_trafico"/>
```

en PreferenciasAjustes llamo de la siguiente manera

```
public static  final String MODO_TRAFICO="modoTrafico"; 
public static boolean modoTrafico; 
public static void obtenerPreferencias(SharedPreferences preferences, Context context) {  
modoTrafico=preferences.getBoolean(MODO_TRAFICO, false);
```

Comment: Haría falta que pongas el código de la clase PreferenciasAjustes, al menos donde se trata la parte relacionada a ese boolean. Además, esa notación en java no es muy común, lo suyo es usar un getter para obtener un valor, no hacer público una variable que, por lo que veo, imagino que viene de una configuración guardada en el dispositivo.

Comment: en el xml  esta  de la siguietnte forma 
` <SwitchPreferenceCompat
            app:key="modoTrafico"
            app:title="Habilitar tráfico"
            app:summary="Habilitado solo en modo Normal"
            android:defaultValue="false"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_trafico"/>`
en PreferenciasAjustes llamo de la siguiente manera
`public static  final String MODO_TRAFICO="modoTrafico"; public static boolean modoTrafico; public static void obtenerPreferencias(SharedPreferences preferences, Context context) {  modoTrafico=preferences.getBoolean(MODO_TRAFICO, false);`

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y añade el código que mencionas aquí, porfavor

Comment: taambien intente de  esta forma  Boolean trafico= valueOf(PreferenciasAjustes.modoTrafico);
        hMap.setTrafficEnabled(trafico); 

al darle el debugger si se verifica que ->PreferenciasAjustes.modoTrafico=true

ahora es  ese true como lo paso a hMap.setTrafficEnabled(??????);

Answer (score 1):

Primero obten la preferencia en base a su llave (key):

```
SwitchPreferenceCompat modoTraficoPref = (SwitchPreferenceCompat) findPreference("modoTrafico");
```

crea un PreferenceChangeListener para obtener los cambios en el Switch, y aquì define el cambio en el mapa:

```
 Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener listener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            //Cambia valor en mapa.
            hMap.setTrafficEnabled((Boolean) newValue);

            return true;
        }
    };
```

Asigna el listener:

```
modoTraficoPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```